# Missing classes in android studio 3.0 canary 4 ui preview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

I'm getting the error that there are classes missing in my XML previewer. So I cannot see my layout in the preview but when I run the app I can see everything just fine.

The classes are inside a module within my android studio project and are included like so:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":styleguide")
}
```

And used in the XML like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.company.packagename.buttons.SecondaryButtonLink
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the button looks like this:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/base_secondary_button_link_ll"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
          android:clickable="true"
          style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.company.packagename.textviews.LabelTextView
        android:id="@+id/secondary_button_link_title_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@drawable/selector_secondary_button_link"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_light_blue"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/button_icon_left_margin"/>

</merge>
```

And the code behind the button class is like this:

```
class SecondaryButtonLink @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    init {
        initializeView(attrs)
    }

    private fun initializeView(attrs: AttributeSet?) {
        val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondary_button_link, this)

        if (attrs == null) return
        checkForImage(attrs)
        val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.StyleGuideButton)
        if (typedArray.hasValue(R.styleable.StyleGuideButton_title)) {
            setButtonTitle(typedArray)
        }

    }

    private fun setButtonTitle(typedArray: TypedArray) {
        for (i in 0..typedArray.indexCount - 1) {
            val attr = typedArray.getIndex(i)
            if (attr == R.styleable.StyleGuideButton_title) {
                secondary_button_link_title_tv.text = typedArray.getString(attr)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun checkForImage(attrs: AttributeSet){
        val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SecondaryButtonLink)
        if (typedArray.hasValue(R.styleable.SecondaryButtonLink_rightimage)) {
            setImage(typedArray)
        }
    }

    private fun setImage(typedArray: TypedArray){
        for (i in 0..typedArray.indexCount - 1) {
            val attr = typedArray.getIndex(i)
            if (attr == R.styleable.SecondaryButtonLink_rightimage) {
                secondary_button_link_title_tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, typedArray.getDrawable(attr),null)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot seem to pin point why it is not showing up in the previewer. Does anyone have an idea why is doesn't show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a bug on android studio Canary 4 you need just to use Canary 1 until they fix it ! :)